# Returning an object with __toString capabilities without the use of a class

Tags: php, oop

I want to return an object to a caller which prints a string when echoed, but also has properties that can be accessed. How can I achieve this without a predefined class and/or a lot of code fluff?

```
$obj = func();   // an object should be returned, where: 
echo $obj->prop; // 1) the object has properties
echo $obj;       // 2) echoing the object itself should echo a specific string
```

Working example by using a class:

```
<?

class obj {

  var $head;
  var $body;

  function __construct($head, $body) {
    $this->head = $head;
    $this->body = $body;
  }

  function __toString() {
    return $this->body;
  }

}

function blah() {

    return new obj("My head", "My body");

}

$response = blah();
echo "$response->head and $response\n";

?>
```

Pseudo-attempt which probably fails:

```
<?

function blah() {

    $head = "My head";
    $body = "My body";

    return (object) array(
        "head" => $head,
        "body" => $body,
        "__toString" => function() {
            return $body;
        },
    );
}

$response = blah();
echo "$response->head and $response\n";

?>
```

Comment: As of PHP7 you can use [anonymouse classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php). Although, I don't see why you require an object? You could just return an array and echo by key `echo $response['head']`. If you're dead set on objects then using a standard class or [typecasting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php#language.types.object.casting) like `$cl = new \stdclass(); $cl->head = $head;` then echo the results by property `echo $res->head . ' and ' . $res->body;` would be an option.

Comment: I want to be able to return an object (`$response`) where I can do just `echo $response` and get a dedicated property (`body` in this case), while also being able to do `echo $response->property` to get any property. Can I do this without a class? Or put differently: What is the shortest way of doing this that requires the least code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [@Narf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/468027/narf) is right, an object *is* an instance of a class, you can do such a thing as [Anonymous Classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php) in PHP 7.

From the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php):

> ```
> <?php
>
> $util->setLogger(new class {
>     public function log($msg)
>     {
>         echo $msg;
>     }
> });
> ```

If you were interested in applying this approach to your situation, you might try something like the following:

```
<?php

$response = new class {
    public function setBody($body) {
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function setHead($head) {
        $this->head = $head;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return (string) $this->body;
    }
};

$response->setHead('200 OK');
$response->setBody('Lorem Ipsum');

echo "$response->head and $response"; // 200 OK and Lorem Ipsum
```

Comment: Anonymous *class*, still a class. ;)

Comment: Not bad! The anonymous class solves the problem with a minimum of code. I'd still like to know if it's possible to use a simple array or object and then do some magic with casting a property or something to achieve the same effect (see my pseudo-example.) Since PHP can generally be coaxed into doing anything...

Answer (score 2):

An object is an instance of a class ... you can't go around that fact.

If you want to put limitations on that class - sure, go for it. It looks like you need the following:

```
final class Response
{
    private $head, $body;

    public function __construct($head, $body)
    {
        $this->head = $head;
        $this->body = $body;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->body;
    }

    public function __get($property)
    {
        return isset($this->$property)
            ? $this->$property
            : null;
    }
}
```

You can only read properties from it and `echo` it, and it's `final` so it can't be extended.